# Simple .Net 5.0 web app getting 404s (using mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, http-status-code-404, asp.net-core-5.0

.Net novice here. I am following along with a web development bootcamp and I have had a persistent issue for the last few days. I've ran it by several TA's, other students, and a few instructors but we have all been stumped thus far.

I am getting 404s when opening the localhost:5000 page in my browser or using postman. The project was generated using the `dotnet new web --no-https -o ProjName` command and then edited.

Here is what my Startup looks like:

```
public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Here is what my controller looks like

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Portfolio.Controllers
{
    class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("")]
        public string Index() => "This is my index";
    }
}
```

Note, I receive a response when using the default auto generated code but not using this Controller with attribute routing pattern. If you know anything about how to resolve this it would be a great help as I am falling behind.

Things I have tried:

- Uninstalling everything related to .net and installing a single version (5.0.100 currently, but I tried a few others as well)
- Uninstalling and reinstalling IIS Express
- Trying to run the project from another computer. No luck.
- Changing the port. No luck.
- Using a different browser. No luck.
- Sobbing on my keyboard. No luck.
- Remaking the same project a dozen times.

I am happy to provide any additional information and I am generally tech savvy enough to follow up on what is suggested.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks to Asier Villanueva for the answer. I didn't set my controller class to public. womp womp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying an empty string in the `HttpGet` attribute is like specifying none.

You can define a default route pattern in the `useMvc`method:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

Or set a slash in the `HttpGet` attribute to set the root path for the method:

```
HttpGet("/")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I attempted both of the solutions you gave and unfortunately the issue persists.

Comment: But which route are you testing with?

Comment: localhost:5000, verified the url in my config files and in the terminal. It is able to connect to the server but it doesn't receive a response on the root route.

Comment: Sorry, you must set the controller class as public too

Comment: I think I have a concussion from the force of my palm hitting my forehead. Thank you. It seems obvious now! It worked finally!